# Is it possible to apply Phaser physics to TileSprite's scroll position?

Tags: javascript, game-engine, phaser-framework

I'm trying to make a game with [top-down perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_graphics#Top-down_perspective) where the player sprite is fixed in the center of screen and the background is moving (scrolling) in the direction opposite to the player's direction, so it results in effect of the player's movement.

I started with these examples: [Invaders](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/games/invaders) (for background scrolling) and [Asteroids Movement](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/asteroids-movement) (for sprite movement). The former uses [`TileSprite`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.1/Phaser.TileSprite.html) and its `tilePosition` property to make vertical scrolling of the background. This works good for linear scrolling in fixed direction (vertical or horizontal). But in my case I need implement scrolling (i.e. movement) in any direction. Furthermore I need such physics features as acceleration and drag, like in the Asteroids example. So I would like to apply Arcade Physics to TileSprite. But it seems that Arcade Physics doesn't work with TileSprite. Or, to be more precise, it doesn't work as I expected.

I've tried to enable Arcade Physics for TileSprite as it used with Sprites. Here is the code:

```
function preload() {
    game.load.baseURL = 'http://examples.phaser.io/assets/';
    game.load.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

    game.load.image('ship', 'games/invaders/player.png');
    game.load.image('starfield', 'games/invaders/starfield.png'); 
}

var player;
var cursors;
var starfield;
var playerAngle = 0; // angle of the player's movement, in degrees
var playerSpeed = 5; // the player's speed, px per frame

function create() {
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    //  The scrolling starfield background
    starfield = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, 'starfield');
    game.physics.enable(starfield, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    starfield.body.velocity.set(200);

    //  The player sprite
    player = game.add.sprite(400, 300, 'ship');
    player.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);

    //  Gameplay controls
    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}

function update() {
    //  Scroll the background
    var delta = 0;
    if (cursors.left.isDown)
        delta = -1;
    else if (cursors.right.isDown)
        delta = 1;
    if (delta)
        player.angle = playerAngle = (playerAngle + delta + 360) % 360;
    var a = (playerAngle + 90) / 360 * 2 * Math.PI; // angle of the background movement/scrolling, in radians
    // move the background by playerSpeed along the a angle
    game.physics.arcade.velocityFromRotation(a, 200, starfield.body.velocity);
}
```

[Try at Phaser sandbox](http://phaser.io/sandbox/rBpQGfEE)

Unfortunately this code doesn't work as I expected.

As far as I understood and as written in [the docs](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.1/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html), Arcade Physics is only intended for work with `Sprite`, not `TileSprite` nor any other game object. If so, this means that I have to manually reproduce all the Physics stuff such as acceleration and drag myself with respect to `TileSprite`. I've written simple `TileSprite` movement with constant velocity (no acceleration, drag and other stuff). Here is the code:

```
function preload() {
    game.load.baseURL = 'http://examples.phaser.io/assets/';
    game.load.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

    game.load.image('ship', 'games/invaders/player.png');
    game.load.image('starfield', 'games/invaders/starfield.png'); 
}

var player;
var cursors;
var starfield;
var playerAngle = 0; // angle of the player's movement, in degrees
var playerSpeed = 5; // the player's speed, px per frame

function create() {
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    //  The scrolling starfield background
    starfield = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, 'starfield');

    //  The player sprite
    player = game.add.sprite(400, 300, 'ship');
    player.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);

    //  Gameplay controls
    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
}

function update() {
    //  Scroll the background
    var delta = 0;
    if (cursors.left.isDown)
        delta = -1;
    else if (cursors.right.isDown)
        delta = 1;
    if (delta)
        player.angle = playerAngle = (playerAngle + delta + 360) % 360;
    var a = (playerAngle + 90) / 360 * 2 * Math.PI; // angle of the background movement/scrolling, in radians
    // move the background by playerSpeed along the a angle
    starfield.tilePosition.x += playerSpeed * Math.cos(a);
    starfield.tilePosition.y += playerSpeed * Math.sin(a);
}
```

[Try at Phaser sandbox](http://phaser.io/sandbox/OoPDpTwx)

Sure it works, however even such simple thing as linear motion require some math knowledge. Other things will require much more knowledge of math and physics. I would not like to implement such things manually.

So is there any way to use Phaser Physics in conjunction with  `tilePosition`?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to rethink the whole thing. Main idea is to **not** make the player sprite fixed, but to make it "dynamic" with physics enabled. To have your desired effect, just make the camera follow the player sprite (with no deadzone). That way, the player remains in the center, and manage the tilesprite classically.

Comment: Thanks for good advice. Although it would be nice to accompany it with some code.

Comment: @hindmost you may want to look at [this](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/camera/basic-follow) camera example from phaser site.

Comment: @Konrad 'Zegis' I've looked at that example as well as others like these: [1](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/camera/smooth-follow), [2](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/camera/fixed-to-camera). The point is that none of the camera examples use angular motion, so "as is" they are useless for me. Have you really tried to adapt that example to my needs? I [tried](http://phaser.io/sandbox/dowAsYWa). And obviously it doesn't work. So it turns out that this answer is useless for me too.